# Does Protractor element.isPresent return a promise or a boolean?

Tags: promise, protractor

The description says it returns a Boolean, but the javascript doc declares it returns a promise:

```
  /**
   * Returns true if there are any elements present that match the finder.
   *
   * @alias element.all(locator).isPresent()
   *
   * @example
   * expect($('.item').isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
   *
   * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
   */
  isPresent(): wdpromise.Promise<boolean> {
    return this.count().then((count) => {
      return count > 0;
    });
  }
```

I am relatively new to the ins and outs of protractor, so I am a little confused with this.

Comment: "*The description says it returns a Boolean*" - which part of the description do you refer to?

Comment: The code that returns a `then()` chain promise should give the ultimate answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

It returns a promise that you need to resolve, either with `.toBe(true)` (boolean) or with something else like:

```
elm.isPresent()
   .then(function(result){
       //do something
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns a Promise, as described in the `@returns` tag and the [isElementPresent](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isElementPresent) documentation.

You're right that the "Returns true if" in the documentation is a bit confusing: Because all of WebDriver's document-querying methods are asynchronous, including [getText](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) and [isEnabled](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isEnabled), they all return promises that resolve to the values you're requesting. You can infer "Returns true" to mean "Returns a promise which resolves to true if".

Additionally, [Protractor uses `jasminewd2`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/webdriver-vs-protractor#jasmine-integration), which is documented to [automatically unwrap promises](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd#features). This means you can use the `expect()` assertion as if the value were synchronous, which further blurs the line between values and promises even as it makes the assertion itself more readable.